# Change the distance of radiobutton Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I am using tkinter for this project. After inputting the radiobuttons, I realize the distance from the box to the icon is different between two radiobuttons.I also try set the same size but it still unchanges.Can anyone help me?

```
s_img = PhotoImage(file = 'fullscreen4.png')
img_label = Label(image = fulls_img)
fulls_btn = Radiobutton(root,image = fulls_img, text="Full Screen", variable=var, value=1,borderwidth =0,bg = '#c3d3f0').place(x = 610, y = 90 )
areas_img = PhotoImage(file = 'area1.png')
img1_label = Label(image = areas_img)
area_btn = Radiobutton(root,image = areas_img, text="Area", variable=var, value=2,borderwidth =0,bg = '#c3d3f0').place(x = 610, y = 150 )
```

[image]

Comment: I've run your code using my own images and find no problem. Try displaying 'fullscreen4.png' in both `Radiobuttons`. You may find the problem is with spacing in image itself not in `tkinter` or `Radiobutton`.

Comment: There's an easy way to check the width of an image, use `img_label.width()` and `img1_label.width()`.

Comment: Could you please put the `fullscreen4.png` and `area1.png` images into your question? This will make it easier to answer your question, since we can use the actual images that you're using.